# How to Configure DockerSecurityOptions for Task Definition using CFT yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I want to restrict docker containers from acquiring additional privileges.
This can be configured on bash using below:

```
docker run --rm -it --security-opt=no-new-privileges ubuntu bash
```

But I want to configure using AWS CloudFormation template. 
Added below code

```
DockerSecurityOptions:
    - "--security-opt"
    - "=no-new-privileges"
```

its throwing me exception 
Docker security option --security-opt must be prefixed with label: or apparmor: (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ClientException;

then tried with

```
DockerSecurityOptions:
    - "--security-opt"
    - "apparmor=no-new-privileges"
```

still same exception while CFT uploads

Answer (score 0):

Just want to make sure the below two conditions are satisfied as mentioned in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html)

> This parameter is not supported for Windows containers or tasks using
> the Fargate launch type.
>
> The Amazon ECS container agent running on a container instance must
> register with the ECS_SELINUX_CAPABLE=true or
> ECS_APPARMOR_CAPABLE=true environment variables before containers
> placed on that instance can use these security options.

Then you can retry with simple syntax as below:

```
DockerSecurityOptions:
    - "no-new-privileges"
```